# SQL Select within a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, select

I have a table with these columns (daystable): `id`, `task_id`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, and `7`. The week starts on Sunday so field 1 is sunday through to Saturday.

For example, a row of data might look like this:

```
 id | task_id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7
----+---------+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
  1 |       3 | 7 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

The idea of the table is to contain data for days that I want to run a query for that day, 1-7 are the days of the week. I started with just having a 0 or a 1, 1 for run the query on that day. 0 don't run it. But I got stuck on how to make the query work so I settled on the following:

```
DECLARE @myvar int;
SET @myvar = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE());
SELECT * 
FROM  daystable 
WHERE ([1] = @myvar OR [2] = @myvar OR [3] = @myvar OR [4] = @myvar 
        OR [5] = @myvar OR [6] = @myvar OR [7] = @myvar)

SELECT t1.name, t2.id, t2.start, t2.end, t3.Description, dt.task_id
FROM   task1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN task2 AS t2 
    ON t1.task_id = t2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN task3 AS t3 
    ON t2.id = t3.task_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN daystable AS dt 
    ON t3.task_id = t3.task_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
```

So the idea is the 0 in the data stayed the same but the 1 I changed for the day of the week number that is returned from DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())

so if I wanted to run the task on a Tuesday on field 3 (Sunday being 1) the data would have a 2 , If I wanted it to run on Sunday, field 1 would have a 7 (Output from DATEPART for Sunday)

This seems to work fine, but maybe a bit messy (Couldn't think of another way of doing it)

My first select query returns the rows from daystable that contain the same number as the @myvar

The second query pulls the data needed from that query.

My issue is I need to join the two queries so I get the one output. The task.id is the field that links all the tables.

I tried:

```
DECLARE @myvar int;
SET @myvar = DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE());
SELECT   t1.name, t2.id, t2.start, t2.end, t3.Description, dt.task_id
FROM  task1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN task2 AS t2 
    ON t1.task_id = t2.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN task3 AS t3 
    ON t2.id = t3.task_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN daystable AS dt 
    ON t3.task_id = t3.task_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
WHERE t1.task_id = (SELECT * 
                    FROM  daystable 
                    WHERE ([1] = @myvar OR [2] = @myvar OR [3] = @myvar 
                            OR [4] = @myvar OR [5] = @myvar 
                            OR [6] = @myvar OR [7] = @myvar))
```

But this didn't seem to work and now I am stuck.

Maybe I have designed the tables wrong but I couldn't work out another way of linking certain days of the weeks with tasks.

Any help would be gratefully received

Comment: what data do you have in your daystable?  can you post sample data and structure of that table?

Comment: Hi @bluefeet, The daystable is the one above: id | task_id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 With the example data : 1 | 3 | 7 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 (Sorry I can't find ou how to format a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Think I've sloved this myself, I used:

```
    WHERE t1.task_id IN (SELECT task_id                      
                 FROM  daystable                       
                 WHERE ([1] = @myvar OR [2] = @myvar
                 OR [3] = @myvarOR [4] = @myvar 
                 OR [5] = @myvar OR [6] = @myvar OR [7] = @myvar))
```

And this seems to work fine. If anyone can think of a better way of doing this then please feel free to share.

But in the mean time, thanks for looking.